# Highlighting Cells based on Active row Values

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, highlight

I am stuck on trying to make my sheet highlight the values in Row 2 based on the Active Cell Row values, in this case I am comparing **cells "B2:F2"** with the **Active Row (B3:F3)** in this case. Here is how the sheet looks before selecting an active cell/row;

[image]

and once I select an active cell (in this case, I selected **cell "A3"**) and would like to compare the **"B3:F3" cell values** with a **static row (B2:F2)** and highlight any cells in the **static row (B2:F2)** that are different than the active row values. The follow screenshot is how the sheet should look once I select **cell "A3"** as the active cell and have the code/conditional formatting combination compare it with the static row values;

[image]

So far, I have this code that highlights the Active cell I am selecting, this is my starting point:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Static xLastRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
xLastRng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
Set xLastRng = Target
End Sub
```

Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense and your suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Did you try any code yet?

Comment: I have tried a few different codes from google and other forums including this one, but so far no luck, I tried using this link to further my understanding of conditional formatting possibilities as well :https://trumpexcel.com/highlight-rows-based-on-cell-value/#Highlight-Rows-Based-on-a-Text-Criteria

Comment: Start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange

Comment: Please post the code you tried.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I posted it

Comment: @BigBen I have started my code with using that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following - basically compare your fixed range `B2:F2` to the corresponding range in the current row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.Range("B2:F2").Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear previous coloring

    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Me.Range("B2:F2")
        If IsNumeric(rng.Value) And IsNumeric(Me.Cells(Target.Row, rng.Column)) Then
            If rng.Value <> Me.Cells(Target.Row, rng.Column).Value Then
                rng.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```